# How do I prevent TypeError blank is undefined?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, undefined, typeerror

Is there an easier way to check if a variable is defined or not in JavaScript when the target is deep within an object? 
For example.

```
// Lets assume this: 
response = {
   status: "simple-message"
}

// running this:
if (response.data.variable_to_check !== undefined) console.log('undefined');
// will result in this:
> TypeError: response.data is undefined
```

In PHP I can run the equivalent check:

```
if (!($response->data->variable_to_check ?? false)) die("Handled Undefined Error");
// will result in this:
> Handled Undefined Error
```

I know I can iterate manually by checking each item starting with the root to see if it's defined, but that seems tedious. That and wrapping everything in a try/catch.

Is there a cleaner / faster / smarter way to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining use babel to emit older javascript equivalents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key)

Comment: @ASDFGerte, This was what I was looking for, yes. Glad to see it's almost here.

And "nested object" was what I was looking for. Couldn't think of the phrase at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
try{
if(response.data.variable_to_check!==undefined){
console.log("undefined");
}
}
catch(err){console.log(err.message)}
```